# dynamically Override onBackPressed of Activity from PopupWindow

Tags: android, overriding, popupwindow

I wrote a class that extends popupwindow.  When the user presses the back key, I would like to handle the back pressed from this class as opposed to having the underlying activity handle it (i.e., I already know about overriding `onBackPressed()`, but this requires modifying the activity's code).  I have a reference of the activity instance.  Is there anyway to override the on back pressed key when the popupwindow is displayed without using the `onBackPressed()` method from within the activity's code?

Comment: Look at reflection in Java. And override method in Activity afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way unless you hijack the back button from the OS and have it broadcast to wake up your app's PopupWindow (I do not suggest doing this).

You should override onBackPressed() or I believe onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) in your Activity to act on/consume the back key (while your activity is in the foreground). As far as having it execute something "dynamic", I'm not exactly sure I understand what you are asking. You can have the code in your PopupWindow class, but call it from onBackPressed() or onKeyDown() through your instance variable in your activity.

Comment: Ah phooey.  That's too bad.  The reason I don't want to modify code for the `onBackPressed()` method is because i was planning on making this a library, and its not exactly fantastic if I have to tell users to modify their activity code.  I am thinking of changing the container for this overlay into a Fragment instead. thanks for your insight

Answer (score 0):

if I am not wrong what you are trying to do actually is invoke the onBackpressed() method of the activity from inside another class.I guess you can define a constructor of your class that takes in a context parameter and using this context you can invoke the onBackPressed() method of your activity. I hope this helps..